# xcode PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: swift

```
/Users/xerasy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Opensoul-azlrvihpzjmefgdiufcpnucguxbp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Opensoul.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Opensoul.build/Script-11B6BEDD1EFAB15300438DBB.sh: line 2: swiftgen: command not found
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

my podfile :

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

def shared_pods
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Result'
    pod 'Reusable'
    pod 'PureLayout'
    pod 'ObjectMapper'
    pod 'Swinject'
end

target 'Opensoul' do
    shared_pods
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Toast'
    target 'OpensoulTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
end


# target 'PlaygroundFramework' do
#     shared_pods
# end
```

i tried

1. > Go to keychain access -> right click on login -> lock & unlock again 
   >   -> clear Xcode project and make build again.
2. `pod install`
3. `pod update`

but nothing helped, how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you try deleting your derived data folder and doing a clean. Then try building again

Comment: @Aggressor i do this, but didn't work (

Comment: Can you try this: 
1. Go to your pods file
2. Comment out ALL the pods
3. Run pod update
4. Cmd + shift + k (runs clean)
5. Uncomment all the pods
6. Run pod update
7. Cmd + shift + k (runs clean again)
8. Build

Comment: @Aggressor again the same error. what else can be done ?

Comment: @Aggressor add new pod -  `pod 'SwiftGen' ` - didnt work ((

Comment: Was this working before? Did you add a build step or build phase that caused this to break?

Comment: @Aggressor this is not my project, my friend gave it to me, it worked well, I cannot understand what the problem is

Comment: Im still not clear. When you say "it worked well", Im wondering what you did before you got this error.

Comment: @Aggressor nothing, i opened project and gives this error. what other reasons could there be for this error ? my friend says that it works well

Comment: Off hand Im not sure. This is some sort of compile issue

Comment: @Aggressor friend have xcode version 9.4.1 I have 10.1 - this could be the reason of the error ?

Comment: You can always download 9.4.1 and try it

Answer (score 0):

Currently my build is working. Here you are the steps I tried until it finally worked:

1. Search in the whole project the word CommonCrypto.
2. If you have a Pod containing that header import, remove this Pod from    the Podfile and perform a pod install. Clean and build the project. Add again the Pod to the Podfile and perform a pod install.
3. Clean and build the
   project again using a real device if possible.

And If you don't have that Pod, maybe you can try by making the same steps with some old Pod that you may encounter in your project.

Added information: also If you have some code error inside a Pod, first you need to solve that code problem and then try to compile again the project.

I'm going to copy the changes made in my project.pbxproj. I know it's not very helpful but it's the only thing that have changed in the git difference commit:

```
Removed: BDC9821B1E9BD1B600ADE0EF /* (null) in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; };
Added:   BDC9821B1E9BD1B600ADE0EF /* BuildFile in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; };
```

Hope this is helpful for you...!

Comment: i finded this word in file `FStringUtilities.m` and `FSRWebSocket.m` - this is `Firebase/Database` module, i deleted `pod 'Firebase/Database'` from podfile and execute `pod install`. clean and build project (get the same error). after this i added again `pod 'Firebase/Database'` and execute `pod install`. clean and build project  - but didnt work, i have the same error